# Gradle Sync Failed In AS : Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am new to Android studio and I am building my app with react-native. When I opened the android studio then Gradle build started and I got this error

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.0/gradle-4.0.0.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :react-native-share-extension
Open File
```

I searched over the stack overflow question, I tried many solutions but nothing worked for me,
What I have already tried
`gradlew clean` , `gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` , `gradlew cleanBuildCache` but these all commands showed the same error log.
Then I deleted `android/.gradle` and `android/.idea` folder also `app.iml` file (but still the same error)
Also I have tried `npm cache clean --force` from react-native project directory
I have also tried `File> invalidate Caches /Restart`.
`android/build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
 
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()

        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io/' }
    }
}
```

`android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
#Wed Jul 08 20:28:12 IST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip
```

`android\app\build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

 
 
 
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    //adding firebase sdk
    
    //adding auth dpendecy manually
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    //implementaion of react native image picker
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        // adding share extension
        implementation project(':react-native-share-extension')
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

 
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
 
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please suggest anything which I am missing here.
Although `npm run android` is working fine and I am able to install the app on the emulator.
[You can see my Gradle version and Gradle plugin version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdxAj.png)

Output of `gradlew tasks --stacktrace`

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-share-extension'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-share-extension:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.0/gradle-4.0.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of
 the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-share-extension

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 13s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am answering my own question. If you are here and you have already tried what I have tried above, then you can give it a try, try deleting the `node-modules` folder and again run `npm install` and literally it worked for me.